# Using Cell Names in CASE

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dynamic Excel spreadsheet where rows are added and removed. For that reason, I can't target cells by using their range. Is it possible to target the cells by using their names in a `case` scenario?

This is my working code right now:

```
Select Case Target.Address


Case "$G$14"
        If Range("RequestorField").Value = "" Then
            Range("RequestorField").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 199, 206)
        Else
            Range("RequestorField").Interior.Color = RGB(215, 228, 188)
        End If
```

Replacing `$G$14` with `RequestorField` kills the code.

Any ideas? Thanks!

**ps: This all goes in the WORKSHEET_CHANGE function, hence the reason why I need to use "case".**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Target.Name.Name`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Select Case Target.Name.Name

    Case "RequestorField"
        If Range("RequestorField").Value = "" Then
            Range("RequestorField").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 199, 206)
        Else
            Range("RequestorField").Interior.Color = RGB(215, 228, 188)
        End If 
    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Alex! It works, however when I try to insert a new row somewhere - I get this error. `Application-defined or object-defined error`. It doesn't like this `Select Case Target.Name.Name`.

Comment: Solved by adding `On Error Resume Next` before `Select Case`